# Como hacer burbujas dinámicas en tamaño en google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Necesito crear marcadores con tamaños dinámicos en forma de burbujas. He buscado librerías y tutoriales pero no puedo encontrar una solución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito algo como esa imágen. 
Gracias por la ayuda !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la [guía de Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=es-419) tienes suficiente información como para hacerlo.

Puedes modificar de forma dinámica para cada marcador su imagen para modificar tamaños por cada localización:

```
var image = {
  url: "URL a una imagen PNG semitransparente de la burbuja",
  size: new google.maps.Size(70, 70), //Utiliza el tamaño que quieras, puedes hacerlo dinámico usando variables
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), //Tendrás que jugar un poco con esto para que quede el punto en el centro de la burbuja, también de modo dinámico
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25) // puedes utilizar esto en vez del size, pero puede que pierdas calidad en la burbuja
};
```

También podrías utilizar las [Drawing tools](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools?hl=es-419), pero tal vez seria más complejo que la opción anterior.

Comment: quedo perfecto, muchas gracias